# Jquery is working inside a function but only for one of the calls, the other I must manually execute in the Chrome console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js

I am trying to reset the 'selected' item after the user makes a selection. This is calling to the Vue function below, tS(). The first call `$('#sel1').prop('selectedIndex',0);` only works if I execute it in the console however the second one  `$('#current-schedule-holder').text('Current : '+scheduleToTime(msg));` works fine, meaning that jquery is working. Also my `console.log($('#sel1'))` shows that the element from the first call, the one that is not working, is already in the DOM when the function executes.

```
tS: function(msg){
   $('#sel1').prop('selectedIndex',0);
   console.log($('#sel1'))
   $('#current-schedule-holder').text('Current : '+scheduleToTime(msg));
   toggleScheduler(this.query, msg);
},
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Vuejs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend mixing jQuery and Vue. Vue uses a virtual DOM while jQuery does not. What's probably happening is that when the tS function runs, it updates the DOM correctly, but then Vue overrides those changes based on the info it has in its virtual DOM.

See https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/20/vue-js-safely-jquery-plugin/ for instructions on how to get jQuery to work with Vue. You're going to have to wrap your jQuery functions in a Vue component which is fine if your needing some complicated functionality in a jQuery plugin, but for basic DOM manipulation like this, it's much easier to stick to doing this inside of Vue.

Comment: I avoided mixing the two and solved my issues. Thanks! Sorry I took so long to accept the answer.

Comment: Thank you for coming back and accepting my answer. I'm glad you where able to get things working.